# A question more related with history than politics and another seeking resources

Tags: discussion, scope

1. I've just found the linked question:

[How many new settlements did Israel build in the last decade in the West Bank?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8698/how-many-new-settlements-did-israel-build-in-the-last-decade-in-the-west-bank)

How is this question related with politics? It seems it is more related with history than politics.

2. Another question:

[EU refugee quota proposal](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12340/eu-refugee-quota-proposal)

The OP asks

> (1) I would like to read the proposal of the EU refugee quota system.

Why? Why would you like to read it? No explanation on why it is needed.

> (2) Could someone tell me, where to find it?

Well, it doesn't seem so difficult to find it and the answer posted proves it. It reads more like a general reference or resource-request (Googling service) type of question.

Can anyone tell me why these two questions are considered on-topic on Politics SE?

Comment: See also https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history

Answer (score 1):

Israeli settlements in the Wet Bank is of great political interest because there is conflict in that area that has to do with those settlements.

The number of new settlements built in the area would be very useful to someone who is interested in understanding those conflicts.  Therefore, it is on topic.

It's likely on-topic for History.SE too, but being on-topic for another SE does not automatically make a question off-topic for Politics.SE.

Comment: You need to fix the first sentence. Now, I **didn't** say Israel settlements in the West Bank is NOT of great political interest. I said asking Politics SE users to count them is **NOT** on topic.

Comment: @Rathony It's important to know that it's of political interest in order to understand why it is on topic.  Even if _you_ already know that it is of political interest, if that bit remains unsaid, it would be difficult for other users to consume this answer.

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by your comment.

Comment: @Rathony The first sentence of my answer is important because the rest of my answer doesn't make sense without it.

Answer (score -1):

The last decade is too recent to be described as history.  It would have to be answered through official data from governments, not secondary sources (papers, books, etc.).

It's part of the background data for current discussions of the situation in Israel, which is an intensely political situation.

> Why? Why would you like to read it? No explanation on why it is needed.

So?  Who cares?  Any explanation why would likely render this off-topic, as it probably relates to the poster's opinions on the subject.

> Well, it doesn't seem so difficult to find it and the answer posted proves it.

That doesn't make the question off-topic, it makes it a bad question.  That's a reason for a down vote in the Stack Exchange system, not a vote to close.

Comment: Why would explaining the reason the OP needs the info. would render it more off-topic than it is? At least, the question could have the reason for the asking itself. A question should have a background information that prompted the OP to ask a question. Don't you agree? Who cares? I do. BTW, what is so intensely political in Israel? What does counting  settlements in Israel have to do with political situation? **Politics Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for people interested in governments, policies, and political processes.** Where does it belong?

Comment: @Rathony  Explaining why the OP needs the info would not render it off-topic, but that doesn't mean that it's necessary.  Apparently, the information the OP is asking for is specific enough that you don't need to know why the OP wants it in order to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: @SamIam Well, you need to direct this comment to the OP of this answer.

Comment: @Rathony  The answerer automatically gets notified of comments on his answer regardless of whether or not I tag him.

Comment: @SamIam You really think I don't know that? Did you even read this answer?

Comment: @Rathony  Well, you did tell me _"you need to direct this comment to the OP of this answer."_  What else am I to think?

Comment: @SamIam Read the answer slowly and my comment.

Comment: @Rathony  I know what the answer and comment say.  I notified you with my comment because I wanted both you and Brythan to see it.  Part of my comment was directed at you, and was explaining to you why it is not even necessary that the OP explain why he needs the info.

Comment: @SamIam  Explaining why the poster wants to know does not in and of itself make the question off-topic.  However, most explanations would do so.  E.g.  "I want to know because I think Israelis are dirty stinking liars!" or "I want to know because Palestinians are liars!" would make the question opinion-based.  And since this is asking for a fact related to a subject that often deals in such rhetoric, I think many explanations will end up as less extreme versions of those statements.  We shouldn't encourage people to rant.

Comment: @Brythan "I want to know because Palestinians are liars!" might be offensive, and It should be edited out of the question, or if it's bad enough, get the question deleted, but It does not fundamentally change the question, and it does not cause the question to be opinion based.