# Do we want a Russo-Ukrainian war tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Note: I am using the term Russo-Ukrainian war because that is the term used on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War).

Seeing as how we have quite a few questions on the war, do we want a tag for it? Having the tag will make it much easier to search for questions on the topic.

Comment: Do we have other tags for conflicts like this? I think this should follow what we have in use in other places.

Comment: @JoeW we have [tag:world-war-ii], [tag:cold-war], and [tag:war-on-drugs], and maybe others.

Comment: I do kindof feel like we should, but there isn't a lot of precedent for it.  Most conflicts we just label with the countries (e.g. [tag:afghanistan]).  There is an [tag:armed-conflict], but that's not specific.  If this escalates into [tag:world-war-iii], that'd be a different story.

Comment: FWTW, they've added such tag on Skeptics, although it's mostly so such questions can be closed as off-topic there, as getting accurate info is often hard. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russo-ukranian-war

Comment: It's the biggest proxy war between the West and East since the cold war. I have a  feeling this will turn out to be more significant in the long run than just territorial changes in Ukraine.

Comment: I like the idea of having it as a temporary tag. When the war is over the tag can be discontinued for future use, but users can still search for them. Is this allowed by the site?

Comment: @QuantumWalnut I don't think that's currently allowed, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not strongly opposed since this is going to be an historic major conflict and perhaps the first of such since Politics SE has taken off.

However, to supplement [@ Gary2's No answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6206/16047) these questions can *or should be able to* be found via a double or triple tag search:

- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation+ukraine+armed-conflict (**45** questions)
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ukraine+armed-conflict (**58** questions)

by typing some combination of `[russian-federation] [ukraine] [armed-conflict]` in the search bar.

However for that to work we should keep an eye on accurate tagging.

Perhaps a review of all questions over the last month with the "highly active" post notices the moderation team has been adding could double check that they have at a minimum two of the three tags above is all that's needed to ensure their representation in future searches.

Comment: A problem with double or triple tag is it limits what other tags can be used as we have a 5   tag limit.

Comment: @JoeW a problem with adding those other tags is that it limits the number of tags that make the question findable in searches via the `armed-conflict` and `ukraine` tags! Can you think of a question about *armed conflict in Ukraine that should not have those two tags?* That's really a generic comment that can be added to any advice about tagging. That said, I think your argument could certainly be added to your answer to make its argument more convincing!

Comment: @JoeW you must also examine the pros and cons of going back and re-tagging the ~40 questions asked this year with the new tag. It kicks them all back into the active question queue I believe unless there is moderator magic to avoid that, not that it's necessarily a bad thing, it just needs to be considered. I've implemented retagging campaigns of almost 100 questions by doing it in smaller batches over weeks. It's not hard if nobody complains.

Comment: @JoeW A new tag would make the problem worse. Most questions tagged [russo-ukrainian-war-2022] should still be tagged with [russia] and [ukraine] and [armed-conflict] since they are clearly about those topics. Now we've just added another tag on top of them

Comment: I am not sure that adding the tag to all those questions would cause an issue and it can be done over a few days to not just push them all back to the top. There are also ways to add the tag without pushing them to the top. As for the multiple tags I would guess some of the ones about what NATO is doing don't need the armed-conflict tag and there are others that involve the situation but are not about the fighting directly. As for the multiple tags I don't see how that is a valid point as having to add 3/2 tags to a question for searching really limits what you can also add

Comment: Not to mention if you search for armed-conflict and ukraine that could pull up unrelated results about past or future armed-conflicts in the areas

Comment: @divibisan And I would argue that not all questions about what is going on need the armed-conflict tag

Comment: @JoeW you could sort by date, it's easy since Newest is the default display.  And of course for questions that aren't about armed-conflict, the easiest solution is don't add it. **But now your new tag needs a more complicated definition**, so you might add an example of what the proposed tag's excerpt should look like to ensure it's scope is well defined.

Comment: Search by date when that is the date asked which has nothing to do about what time period is being asked about. Someone could ask a question tomorrow a question with armed-conflict, ukraine, ww2 and it would show up in the search before other questions about the current conflict. A date search is just when the question was asked.

Comment: @JoeW yes that's a good point, it works now, but won't work in the future.

Comment: It might not even work now depending on what questions get asked with those tags

Comment: @JoeW in what cases would a question with the "Russo-Ukrainian war tag" not be about armed conflict? If you can outline some, then adding that to your answer also enhances its position and argues against mine.

Comment: Look on the front page, I can see a number of questions about the conflict that do not have the armed-conflict tag and appear to not need them

Comment: @JoeW you are making good arguments, why not go back and review all these comments, find all the convincing points and add them [to your answer post](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6205/16047) so that 1) I can reverse my down vote, 2) others can up vote, and 3) a new tag can be born!

Comment: @divibisan [tag trees](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367906/magic-wand-time-what-does-your-community-need/367983#367983), if they ever get implemented, would be a solution for that problem. I don't know what the company has planned for them right now however.

Comment: @JoeW I can't reverse my vote on your answer until an edit has been made. Going from -3 to -1 will make it more visible. You've made some excellent arguments in comments here, but they will reach a lot more readers if added to an answer post as well.

Answer (score 2):

No. We didn't have a US presidential election 2020 tag, we have presidential election tag.

So, we don't need Russo-Ukrainian crisis tag, Armenia-Azerbaijan crisis tag, etc.

For a history site, specific event tags are good. For politics we don't need it.

> Having the tag will make it much easier to search for questions on the topic.

Naah. The search facility is very good in stack exchange. We can just search "Russia Ukraine". It would match the words in the body. And present day, Russian federation tag just shows everything on the war.

> we have world-war-ii, cold-war, and war-on-drugs,

These things went on for years. These things shaped history. These things have philosophy embedded in them. Movies are made on these. These are way bigger, not comparable to what is happening in Ukraine.

If this is made, tomorrow someone would make Balochistan offence on Pakistan, Naxal offence of India, North Korean haircuts, ....

Comment: This is an event that is still ongoing with no end in sight, I think it is to early to say how this will end or how big it will get.

Comment: What about Myanmar? What about Venezuela? What is naxal offence in India? The Ukraine conflict appears to be having a large impact and there are lots of questions around it which is why a tag has been suggested. If there are lots of questions around the other issues you are talking about maybe a tag is appropriate for them. As for your example of the 2020 election we already have lots of tags that nicely fit the questions and a new one wasn't needed. The question here is if a new one is needed here which I think it could be useful.

Comment: "We didn't have a US presidential election 2020 tag..." but oddly there is a `republican-primary` tag with only 17 questions.

Comment: *These are way bigger, not comparable to what is happening* ... well, we hope.

Comment: @uhoh - Presumably, that would apply to any US Republican primary, in any year, and isn't just a single cycle's primaries.

Comment: @Bobson the analogy is imperfect (as all analogies must be) but rather than a single event with a clear beginning and end like a single cycle's primary, [(t)he Russo-Ukrainian War **is an ongoing war** between Russia (together with pro-Russian separatist forces) and Ukraine. **It began in February 2014**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War) *At least* eight years long and with no end in sight and global participation, good arguments could be made for (as well as against) a tag that put it on a similar footing to other existing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Two years later https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-federation+ukraine+armed-conflict has 148 questions, so about 100 more than when the full invasion started. This is more than enough to justify a tag. Tag space is limited to 5. Having to use 3 tags instead of 1 is a fair concern. Skeptics [does](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russo-ukrainian-war) have such a tag, for merely 26 Qs. That's about par with the [WW2 tag here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-ii) -- 30 Qs. Or [cold war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-war) -- 21 Qs. (FWTW, the more recently created [2023-israel-hamas-war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2023-israel-hamas-war) has 130 Qs here. This seems normal to me for a site with focus on [current politics](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history).)

And the argument that the Russo-Ukrainian war didn't "shape history" is certainly silly in 2024. Finland and Sweden joined NATO as a result, etc.

BTW, the way the quick search box works for tags, it finds these extra tags pretty easily; in fact the sort order seem to be how many Qs are under that tag. So an 'extra' ukraine tag will pop up pretty easily there, just as the hamas (war) one does. In fact the sort order seem to be how many Qs are under that tag.

[image]

Right now, for "Ukr" I get a single completion, so it's not like an extra ukraine-war tag would drown out the completion/search box:

[image]

There is somewhat of a problem that the top search bar doesn't currently offer any completions for any tags:

[image]

TBH, the latter is general/global issue that Stack Exchange should fix. (They could switch from that help to completions once you start typing something.) The latter [has been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107094/tag-completion-in-search-bar) a feature request for over 10 years now, so I'm not holding my breath though.

Answer (score -3):

We have other tags already that are similar so I see no problem in adding one for this. This seems to follow existing patterns on the site

[world-war-ii](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-ii)

[cold-war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cold-war)

[war-on-drugs](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/war-on-drugs)

Answer (score -5):

Nah. Otherwise, every little war will have its own little tag, and we will have a sea of tags.

But if this war, God forbid, becomes WWIII, then just add the [world-war-iii](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-iii) tag. The last tag on this site, that will be - sorry, folks. Make sure you back up this site onto some thermostable material when this tag shows up.