# Should we Burninate 2023-israel-hamas-war?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

As of right now the tag [2023-israel-hamas-war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2023-israel-hamas-war) has been used 130 times on the main site.

I think this tag shouldn’t exist for the [same reasons that the russo-ukraine war tag shouldn’t exist](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6208/27084), which is because it takes up space in the 5-tag limit and questions about this could be found by searching a combination of [armed-conflict](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armed-conflict), [israel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel), and [hamas](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamas).

Note: if we do decide to burninate [2023-israel-hamas-war](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2023-israel-hamas-war) we would replace it with [armed-conflict](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/armed-conflict), [israel](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/israel), and [hamas](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hamas).

Comment: Wouldn't that single tag take the space of those other 3 tags. Also that question you linked appears to be in support of a russo-ukraine tag with more people agreeing that it should then those opposed to it.

Comment: @JoeW the question I linked was a discussion on whether or not we should add the tag, not a request to add the tag, and all of the highest voted answers said no. Maybe I should have linked to an answer instead, but idk. Also, the reason that I disagree with your reasoning about the single tag taking the space of those three other tags is because those questions should still be findable by the other three tags, so my solution is replacing 4 tags with 3.

Comment: see also: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6204/do-we-want-a-russo-ukrainian-war-tag#comment15005_6208

Comment: Yes, and it is titled "Do we want a Russo-Ukrainian war tag?" and the answer on that say that yes we do want it. The way you have it in your question makes it seem like the question and answers are suggesting that we don't want a "russo-ukrainian" war tag which is not the case. You shouldn't be using a different title for the question and making it seem like it said we don't want that tag.

Answer (score 5):

No, that tag is for  a particular conflict at a particular point in time, with exceptional circumstances.

Hopefully the next time there's a problem in the area it will be of a less exceptionally bloody nature.

Separating out this horrible mess from other, past and future, Israeli-Palestinian issues seems useful.

Answer (score 3):

There are 130 question under this 2023-israel-hamas-war tag. And 148 under the russia-ukraine-war putative tag. These are arguments *for* having such tags.

Yes, I can see the argument that not having the country tags [added] makes it more difficult for someone unaware of these special tags to find them. YMMV. I'm not sure there's a good compromise in this regard. But a text search will likely find a Q so tagged (with the dedicated war tag), and that should clue in anyone searching for more.

BTW, the way the quick search box works for tags, it finds these extra tags pretty easily; in fact the sort order seem to be how many Qs are under that tag.

[image]

There is somewhat of a problem that the top search bar doesn't currently offer any completions for any tags:

[image]

TBH, the latter is general/global issue that Stack Exchange should fix. (They could switch from that help to completions once you start typing something.) The latter [has been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107094/tag-completion-in-search-bar) a feature request for over 10 years now, so I'm not holding my breath though.