# Discretion in Stack edge cases and best practices

Tags: discussion

The answers to this [question](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5836/cutoff-between-politics-and-history) seem to point to the history/politics cutoff being a discretionary thing, based on context. [Some](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/has-there-ever-been-an-instance-of-a-larger-country-saying-neither-of-you-get-i?noredirect=1#comment237392_72610) seem to believe that the discretion should be based on date. But it seems like more and more frequently, using the word 'history' in a politics post gets it moved to History.

I understand the need to have flexibility in judgment, but it seems like having some general rules/guidelines/best practices for moderators to consider would provide more consistent results. Is this worth pursuing?

Answer (score 3):

I think the question does belong on history as it is asking about has this ever happened and is not limiting to to a specific time period. As this answer could include things that happened hundreds or thousands of years ago and not be applicable to current situations it is a better fit on history.

If you had limited it in scope to more recent history it would be a fit on politics.

Comment: That's fine, but having at least some guidelines means that we don't have to depend on 'feeling', we can say, 'it fits in this bucket for x y z reasons'.

Comment: @Carduus The problem is that what might be on topic can change based on current events. Something that might be purely history related could become completely on topic the next day based on current events.

Comment: When you try to make rules to solve this problem, all you get are rules, not solutions. There is always another case that does not fit the rules, meaning more rules. At what point do you accept some judgement is required?